# Fixed header and footer and 100% height content

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a site with a fixed header and footer, then have a content div in between that fills the window (like height 100%) without pushing the footer below the fold.

I have created this JSFiddle to illustrate what I'm trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/CZFBE/

```
<body>
<header>
    <nav>Menu</nav>
</header>
<section>
    <div class="hero">Hello World</div>
</section>
<footer>
    Copyright lol
</footer>
</body>
```

I need the section element to fill the empty screen space. Is this at all possible? I've been trying to solve this for days now and I appreciate any help or ideas!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you edit the link ? There is a 404 error.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/CZFBE/ is the correct link

Answer (score 1):

I've updated your code in JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/CZFBE/2/

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    height:100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
header {
    width:100%;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    background: grey;
    height: 4em;
    position:absolute;
}
section {
    height: 100%;
    background: lightgrey;
}
.hero {
    text-align: center;
}
footer {
    width:100%;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    position:absolute;
    background: grey;
    height: 4em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that, it works for me:

```
header, footer, section{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
}
header, footer{
    height: 10%;
}
header{
    top: 0;
}
footer{
    bottom: 0;
}
section{
    height: 80%;
    top: 10%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Both header and footer take 10% space and doesn't move, section take the rest and scroll.

Comment: Plus, if you need to place something absolutely in the section, use `position:relative;` on a wrapper div inside which has width and height at 100%

Comment: Thanks, but problem is I need the footer and header to have a fixed height (like 4em), not a percent value.

Comment: I think pixels or other values should work, just set top and bottom value of section to the heights of header and footer respectively instead of setting a height to the section

Answer (score 0):

check out this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CZFBE/1/)

If you give the `body` and `html` `height:100%`

You can do it by giving your `section` a `height:100%` aswell

Given you needed fixed footer + header, this is what I came up with

```
body,html{
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
header{
    background: grey;
    height: 4em;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
section{
    background: lightgrey;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top:4em;
}
.hero{
    text-align: center;
}
footer{
    background: grey;
    height: 4em;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this gives me a scroll. When I scroll down, "Test." disappears behind the menu.